# $6\tan^2 x-3\cos^2x=\cos 2x$ Need some hints.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $6\tan^2 x-3\cos^2x=\cos 2x$, then what is the value of $\cos 2x$?

Can anyone give me some hints for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identities $\tan^2{x}=\sec^2{x}-1$ and $\cos{2x} = 2\cos^2{x}-1$ to write everything in terms of $\cos{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Let $\cos^2x= t \implies \tan^2x = \dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}=\dfrac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}=\dfrac{1-t}{t} ; \cos {2x}=2\cos ^2 x -1.$ Put this in your equation.It will be a quadraic equation in $t$, solve for $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Set $t=\tan x$, $u=\cos 2x$, then use the formulae:
$$\cos^2x=\frac1{1+t^2},\qquad u=\cos 2x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},$$
from which you deduce
$$t^2=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1+ \cos 2x}=\frac{1-u}{1+u}.$$
You'll obtain a quadratic equation in $u$.